# Error retrieving access_token on Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook

I have a problem with the Facebook's API.
This is my code:

```
    require_once "facebook-php-sdk/facebook.php";

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId'  => '(the app code)',
     'secret' => '(the secret code)',
     'cookie' => true,
    ));     

    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $uid = "(my user id)";

    $feed = $facebook->api("/{$uid}/feed?access_token={$access_token}&limit=5");
```

print_r($feed);
This code doesn't work, the *$access_token* is empty. Why?
I have the offline_perms and also all perms for read the wall...
I wanna make a script for read my status (just writed by me!)
Where is the problem? Can someone help me?
I can't use cURL because on my server it's deactivated and I can't ask to enable it because it's just a free hosting. Is there another way to retrive the access token?
Thanks so much. Sorry for my English, but I'm not it. See you! :)

Answer (score 1):

> I can't use cURL because on my server it's deactivated and I can't ask to enable it because it's just a free hosting.

You don't wanna hear it but ... **Bad idea**.

Answer (score 1):

You should really learn how to read error messages, Please read it carefully:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost/site/others/content.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Programmi\AppServ\www\site\others\content.php on line 19
```

Lets break it down:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost/site/others/content.php)
```

This means that this functions has triggered a **Warning**

```
[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Programmi\AppServ\www\site\others\content.php on line 19
```

This is the reason the error was triggered, looking at it you can see that it says:

> No such file or directory in C:\Programmi\AppServ\www\site\others\content.php on line 19

file_get_contents is unable to see the file being requested, ie:

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost/site/others/content.php

So if file_get_contents is not able to see the facebook domain, I would recommend getting a server where curl is enable or at least the file_get_contents is fully supported.